# Using a Proxy, VPN, Anonymizer

Tags: windows-10

I am having difficulty applying to jobs because of Proxy, VPN &/or Anonymizer. Where do I go on my computer to disconnect the Proxy VPN &/or Anonymizer so I can apply for important employment opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able configure VPN or Proxy under Settings > Network & Internet

VPN - here you can disconnect from a VPN if there is.
Proxy - This is typically set to default which is "automatically detect settings". change it if its not.

Few things to keep in mind, if you did not set up a proxy/vpn(manually or via commercial software (e.g. NordVPN,expressVPN,OpenVPN) on your laptop, The proxy/VPN might be configured in the network the you are connected or your ISP restriction accessing sites(depending your country's policy), if either these two are the case then you might need a VPN/proxy to be able to access the jobs/sites you are trying to reach.